# Send to Deliverability Seed List - Use case? and more details!

Tags: marketing-cloud, return-path-platform

Can anyone help me to understand this WEIRD concept - **Send to Deliverability Seed List** Any real-time use case scenario would help to understand this concept better.

I went through this official documentation and my understandings are as below,
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_inbox_monitor_seedlist_send.htm&type=5

- Select the below checkbox to include the seed list.
  [image]
- Once the Email is deployed to to **Return Path Platform**
  [image]
- Then when I noticed lot of information being pulled, like different Mail box providers, which customers are opening the email etc...
- [image]

Also it would be helpful, where to get some tutorial videos or links on how to use each of this feature to increase ROI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Return Path](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us) is essentially a third party tool within Marketing Cloud, so all the documentation you'll find is hosted on the [Return Path Help Center](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us).

There is a [Marketing Cloud documentation page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_return_path_platform.htm&type=5) which links everything back to that Return Path Help Center.

To answer your question, Auto-Seeding happens when you send to more than 10,000 subscribers if you have Inbox Monitor deliverability. Inbox Monitor is essentially just email addresses at each specific email provider that Return Path owns and monitors. When you send an email out, they check each of these email addresses to see if the email made it to the inbox. For example, Return Path may manage a few email addresses like:

- returnpath001abc@gmail.com
- returnpath001abc@yahoo.com
- returnpath001abc@aol.com

Then when you send an email from MC (with over 10,000 subscribers), it will automatically add those deliverability seed email addresses to your send. Or you can manually check the checkbox "*Send to Deliverability Seed List*." Then it monitors those email addresses and checks if it makes it to the inbox or junk folder.

There are authentication measures done in the Sender Authentication Package (SAP) such as DKIM, SenderID, and SPF that should help to get you inboxed, but depending on your list or content, you may or may not get inboxed.

There are some [videos in the Return Path Help Center](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028865051-Return-Path-Platform-feature-updates-June-2019-video-) that may help explain deliverability and Return Path capabilities to you further.

Comment: I have a question on data and privacy... If you are sending a highly dynamic email to say 500k people that includes account information etc., what version of the email is sent to the return path seed list?